# Firebase getValue(Class.class) Object

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to get data from Firebase into an Object but it is returning null for the values.

My Firebase database is as follows:

```
- Reports
    - RandomID
        - Name: Bob
        - Value: x
```

etc

My Report Class is as follows:

```
public class Report {
    private String name;
    private String value;


    public Report() {
    }

    public Report(String name, String value) {
        this.name= name;
        this.value= value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value= value;
    }
```

I have a database addChildEventListener in which on the onChildAdded method i do the following:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Reports");
mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Report currentReport = dataSnapshot.child(s).getValue(Report.class);
                    Log.d("CurrentReport", "Name: "currentReport.getName() + " Value: " + currentReport.getValue()));
                    Log.d("MyReports", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
```

the `currentReport.getName()` and `getValue()` are returning null
but `dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()` is returning:
    `{Name=Bob, Val= x}`

How can i store this in Report without doing Report x = new Report(...)

Thanks

Comment: can you show your ChildEventListener? I think you might have to remove the child(s)

Comment: It would also help if you showed us your Report class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{Name=Bob, Val= x}` doesn't match your object.

Case matters.

```
private String name;
private String value;
```

---

Options

1) Update Java object: `private String Name, Val;`

2) Update Firebase to have `name` and `value` be the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I return your object encapsulated.

```
mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null)
        {
            Report = dataSnapshot.getValue(Report.class);
        }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
//---
            }
        });
```